# Does willMoveToSuperview will also deallocate the UIView on which its got called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I was wondering if I can call willMoveToSuperview on UIView and after that retain that view to reuse later for one ? something like following

```
    if (!CGRectIntersectsRect(cell.frame, visibleRegion)) {
    [cell willMoveToSuperview:nil];
    [self.resuableCells addObject:cell];
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `willMoveToSuperview:`? You are not supposed to call that. It will be called by the framework at the appropriate time. What is your goal here?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your intent here...

But **WillMoveToSuperview** - According to doc:

> The default implementation of this method does nothing. Subclasses can override it to perform additional actions whenever the superview changes.

So your code,

> [cell willMoveToSuperview:nil];

Has no effect unless you override this method in a cell subclass and implement your own logic there.

Coming to your question -

> Does willMoveToSuperview will also deallocate the UIView on which its got called?

Answer is obvious - NO.

Answer (score 0):

willMoveToSuperview is an observer method that the system calls as a courtesy to you in order to give you a chance to handle special cases before it completes some other hidden tasks.

It's default behavior is to do nothing, but you might want to tidy up something in your code prior to a move by overriding this method.

A proper use case might be if you had a view playing a video clip or an animation, and something else in your code is about to rip the view out of it's current hierarchy and place it in some other un-related view hierarchy. You might want the chance to pause the clip or suspend the animation before the move took place.

I doubt it's the right method to handle what you are attempting, and I definitely know you should not be calling it directly.

Feel free to post some more code to show us what you're trying to accomplish and where it's going wrong.